# User Management and Token based authentication in AWS Cognito and AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, fastapi, aws-api-gateway

I am running a simple Rest API based on FastAPI. This API runs in a AWS Lambda container. I have added API Gateway as a trigger.

Now I want to secure this API.

My expectation:

- I create a User and a Password manually
- The user can call a specific endpoint with his User and Password to receive an access token
- With this access token the user should be able to access the API e.g. by passing a Bearer Token.

Actually I have tried AWS Cognito, but the only way to receive an access token is to use the CLIENT_ID and the CLIENT_SECRET. And I don't want to share this to external users of the API.

I think this CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET is made for a web-app or sth. like that but this is not what I want. I just need a simple pipeline of: user creation -> user login -> Access_token -> API.

I hope anyone of you is able to share a guide or similar. Maybe AWS Cognito is not made for such a use case , if you think so then just let me know and why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes, absolutely it's possible, please refer below image.

1. In the first step your app user signs in through a user pool and
   receives user pool tokens after a successful authentication.
2. Next, your app exchanges the user pool tokens for AWS credentials
   through an identity pool.
3. Finally, your app user can then use those AWS credentials to access
   other AWS services such as Amazon S3 or DynamoDB.

[image: Cognito]

later on you need some custom authorizer in API-Gateway (lambda) to validate the token.